# material-ui change the height of the drawer

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react and material-ui in my project and I have come across a simple issue that I just dont't know how to solve.
I want to create a drawer and set its height in a way that when it will open, it wont open over the app bar.

There is no parameter in the Drawer component for the height, I also tried to override its style and setting up the height on the style object like this :

```
<Drawer style={{height:'90%'}} />
```

But it didn't work.

The only way I can think of, is editing the code of the Drawer component, but ofcourse I want to avoid that.

Any idea on how I can define the height?

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in a div and changing the height of that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<Drawer open={this.state.open} containerStyle={{height: 'calc(100% - 64px)', top: 64}}>
  <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I can't +1 to your answer because I don't have enough rep, I will do it when I'll be able to

Comment: Any idea how to get the zDepth in minus??

Comment: `containerStyle` is not a supported attribute in current version 3.1.2

Comment: As you'll probably guess from the date of the question (and answer) it relates to v0. With v1 onwards you can use the `className` prop to pass in a CSS class.

Answer (score 13):

**containerStyle** is prohibited in version 1.0 and above

So you need to use props **classes** instead

Here is an example to this nontrivial case

```
import {withStyles, createStyleSheet} from 'material-ui/styles'
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet({
  paper: {
    height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
    top: 64
  }
})
class CustomDrawer extends Component {
  ...
  render () {
    const classes = this.props.classes
    return (
      <Drawer
        classes={{paper: classes.paper}}
      >
      ...
    )
}

CustomDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styleSheet)(CustomDrawer)
```

Comment: 'Paper' is a child of Dock, the height should be on 'drawer' key `classes={{docked: classes.paper}}`

Comment: If I add `height: '100%'` to the `paper` class in my `styles` object the drawer will not go to `100%`... also the `docked:` returns an error in my case. Is there another approach to this?

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Drawer in mui, you can do something like this by passing this prop

```
      <Drawer
        PaperProps={{
          sx: {
            height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
            top: 64,
          },
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

i am now using Material UI and v5.14,

just set the height of the element which in the drawer is ok to me

```
   <Drawer
    anchor="bottom"
    open={open}
    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  >
    <div style={{height:"calc(100vh - 64px)"}}></div>
  </Drawer>
```